# Access HttpContext inside WCF RequestInterceptor ProcessRequest method

Tags: wcf, httpcontext

I have create a WCF service using the WCF REST stater kit. I am using a RequestInterceptor to do authentication(API Key validation).Inside of the RequestInterceptor(ProcessRequest method) I want to get access to the HttpContext of the request.I have  to store several things in the HttpContext.  Can somebody help me how to access the HttpContext inside RequestInterceptor. Although Httpcontext is accessible under service.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, you dont get the HttpContext but you can get to the headers and other aspects that will get you the same data.

```
   var prop = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)requestContext.RequestMessage.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            var queryString = requestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To.AbsolutePath;
            var authAccessToken = prop.Headers["Authorization"];
```